# Best way in Excel VBA to listen for cell changes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to watch a cell for changes. The cell can change many times a second triggerd by some VBA code from a Add-in. I want to count the number of times the value updates.

What I have so far is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Static oldval
    If Range("C3").Value <> oldval Then
        oldval = Range("C1").Value
        Blad1.Range("N18").Value = Blad1.Range("N18").Value + 1
    End If
End Sub
```

The issue is that when I start my Excel sheet the code crashes at once with the error: `Out of stack space`

My question is now why am I getting this error and is this the fastes implementation for what I want to do?

Comment: Why do you compare cell **C3** to `oldval`, but then set the new value of `oldval` to be what is in cell **C1**?

Comment: Yep that did the trick, tired eyes missed that first

Comment: @YowE3K – Please post that as an answer so the question can be resolved. (It's currently [under review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/17785280).)

Comment: @AdamKatz I was thinking the question should be closed due to being a typo, so didn't think it warranted an answer.

Comment: That's a good point, and I hadn't seen that there's already an answer. (The review interface makes that hard to notice.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A question about a stack overflow, on StackOverflow.

Incrementing your counter cell triggers the Calculate event, which increments your counter, which triggers the Calculate event, etc. Use another static variable to prevent recursion. A static variable keeps its value across calls to the procedure that hosts it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Static bWorking as Boolean
    Static oldval As Variant

    If Not bWorking Then
        If Range("C3").Value <> oldval Then
            oldval = Range("C1").Value

            bWorking = True
            Blad1.Range("N18").Value = Blad1.Range("N18").Value + 1
            bWorking = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Also consider @YowE3's comment about why your code sets oldval to C1's value.

**Edit**: as for the performance part of your question, assuming you want to store the counter's value into a cell in real-time, you could make marginal gains by re-using cell references, maintaining the count in a static variable, and using the Value2 property.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Static monitoredCell As Excel.Range
    Static counterCell As Excel.Range
    Static counter As Long
    Static bWorking As Boolean
    Static oldVal As Variant

    If Not bWorking Then
        If monitoredCell Is Nothing Then
            'Initialize the ranges.
            Set monitoredCell = Me.Range("C3")
            Set counterCell = Blad1.Range("N18")
            'Comment out the line below if you don't wish to keep counting from the last saved value.
            counter = counterCell.Value2
        End If

        If monitoredCell.Value2 <> oldVal Then
            oldVal = monitoredCell.Value2
            counter = counter + 1

            bWorking = True
            counterCell.Value2 = counter
            bWorking = False
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this the fastest way to do this sort of thing in VBA?

Comment: @user3139545 working with in-memory values is always going to be faster than working with cells.

Comment: The counter increment will only cause recursion due to the incorrect value being stored in `oldval`.  If the correct value was stored, then the change to cell N18 (**if** it triggers a recalc) would only cause the second invocation of `Calculate` to get to the `If` statement and then exit, thus avoiding the Stack Overflow (oops, I mean the "stack overflow").

Comment: Blad1 is not the same Sheet as the sheet that runs this code, will this Sub really trigger for updates to any Sheet?

Comment: Your counter's worksheet either refers to Blad1, or contains a [volatile function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx#sectionSection2), or some other events trigger a re-calculation of it.