# Excel 2003 - How do I trigger an event when a chart point is dragged?

Tags: excel, vba, events, worksheet-function, excel-2003

I have a chart which is an XY plot of the output of a cubic spline function generator.  The input of the spline is a series of points `(X, Y)`, and these points are also shown on the graph.  The calculation of the spline output is triggered by a VBA `Worksheet_Change` event.  The idea is that the curve generation is interactive - the user enters an X-Y pair, and the spline output graph changes accordingly.

The problem is when I change the point coordinates by clicking and dragging a point with the mouse, the corresponding value in the cell changes, but the event isn't triggered. If I manually change the value, the event is triggered as expected.

Is there a way of generating an event when a point is dragged-and-dropped on a chart?

** UPDATE **

I added a bit of error handling to ensure the `EnableEvents` flag is set again if the recalculation throws an exception:

```
private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

Application.EnableEvents     = False   ' make sure there are no recursive calls
On Error GoTo Finalize                 ' make sure events are re-enabled if we crash in here

RecalculateOutputPoints
Finalize:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Check whether the Worksheet_Calculate event is fired.

Comment: Short answer - yes. `Worksheet_Calculate` fires when I drag and drop a point.  I imagine there is potential for endless recursion if I'm not careful here. The procedure doesn't have any accompanying parameter that I could use to find out what cell triggered the recalculate.  Does this event fire once after (before) every cell is updated?

Comment: See [Worksheet.Calculate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-calculate-event-excel). Note that drag & dropping points on a chart isn't possible since Excel 2007. To counter recursion issues, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47021854/best-way-in-excel-vba-to-listen-for-cell-changes/47021985#47021985).

Comment: I've never seen the point of removing stuff from a product.  I can't see there would be a security issue with drag and drop.

Comment: Turns out Drag & Drop data point functionality hasn't been available **since Excel 2003** (not 2007), but @Excelosaurus & Rossmcm, there is an [add-in on this page](https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2009/11/02/excel-add-in-for-manipulating-points-on-charts-mpoc/?eu=true) to add that feature back in to newer versions.

Comment: I have Excel 2003 and drag and drop off points seems to be supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Worksheet_Calculate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheet-calculate-event-excel) event and the [`EnableEvents`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-enableevents-property-excel) property:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    Application.EnableEvents     = False   ' make sure there are no recursive calls
    On Error GoTo Finalize                 ' make sure events are re-enabled if we crash in here
    Call RecalculateOutputPoints()

  Finalize:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

.

```
Sub RecalculateOutputPoints()

    On Error GoTo Finalize                 ' make sure events are re-enabled 
    ...your code here...

  Finalize:
    Application.EnableEvents=True

End Sub
```

.

### Update:

I stand corrected: your error handling is fine.  I assumed that error handling didn't apply to "child subs" but a quick test proved me incorrect:

```
Sub RunThisSub()
    On Error GoTo gotError
    Call causeError
    Err.Raise 28 'cause "Stack" error
gotError:
    MsgBox "This is after the error"
End Sub

Sub causeError()
    Err.Raise 6 'cause "Overflow" error
End Sub
```

In the test, neither the "Stack" nor "Overflow" errors were display.

Comment: Thanks,  I added a bit of error handling (see question edit)

Comment: Good idea! - except that if the error occured within `RecalculateOutputPoints()`, it wouldn't be caught by the error handling in `Worksheet_Calculate()`, but that's easily fixed.  (I edited my example above.)

Comment: Hmm OK.  Not familiar with VBA error handling.  Are you saying that an unhandled exception in a routine doesn't bubble up to the caller?

Comment: Nevermind, I stand corrected, you were right. I've actually always assumed that the calling sub's error handling wouldn't apply to the "child sub" but I just tested it and you are right, your code was fine. So we both learned something, perfect! With your code, if there was an error `Sub RecalculateOutputPoints()` would cease execution and return to the calling sub, and then `Application.EnableEvents = True` would still re-enable events. :-)